# Не изменяется ширина View

Tags: swift

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    layoutIfNeeded()
    itemButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
    itemButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemGray.cgColor
    if isSupportView {
        itemButton.frame.size.width = 2
    } else {
        itemButton.layer.cornerRadius = itemButton.frame.width/2
    }
}
```

Создаю кастомную View. Если флаг - isSupportView , то изменяю ширину View.Но при запуске ширина не изменяется .Ширину View настраиваю IB
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Общий алгоритм действий при установке констрейнтов в интерфейс билдере и необходимости затем изменить размеры или позицию вью (на примере ширины):

- для констрейнта ширины создаем outlet
- при необходимости изменить ширину в любом методе присваиваем новую ширину

```
widthConstraint.constant = newWidth
```

Кстати в вашем случае будет немного иначе - так как у вас установлены leading и trailing контрейнты, а затем еще и пропорциональный размер, то вам нужно менять размеры именно leading и trailing констрейнтов, создав для них аутлеты, но при этом ваша кнопка будет одновременно менять не только ширину, но и высоту

Answer (score 1):

Ширина в случае подобной разметки будет контролироваться родительским вью и констрейтами в нем. Если необходимо, чтобы вью сама определяла свой размер, тогда нужно переопределить
**intrinsicContentSize**, например так:

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
   return CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
}
```

А вложенные вью уже подстроятся.